# Multiple binding in WPF for boolean converter

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, binding

I'm developing a small application that needs to check some availability properties. I'm using for the user interface WPF. I need to change some foreground colors if a selection from a combobox. I have this DataTemplate:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="userTemplate">
<TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center">
    <Image Source="imgsource.png" Height="25" Width="25" />
    <Run Text="{Binding BooleanObjectName}" Foreground="{Binding boolobject, Converter={StaticResource convAvailability}}"/>
</TextBlock>
```

So I'm using for this convertion a IValueConverter that sets the color to the foreground:

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    BooleanObject boolobject = (BooleanObject)value;
    if (boolobject.IsBoolValueOne) return System.Drawing.Brushes.Green;
    else if (boolobject.IsBoolValueTwo) return System.Drawing.Brushes.Red;
    else if (boolobject.IsBoolValueThree) return (SolidColorBrush)(new BrushConverter().ConvertFrom("#d3d300"));
    else return System.Drawing.Brushes.Black;
}
```

What is wrong with this, because in my interface I'm always getting the black color. Any thoughts on this ?

Any help would be very much appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need a [Brush](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.brushes(v=vs.110).aspx) from the `System.Windows.Media` namespace in a WPF project, the `System.Drawing` namespace is for WinForms.

Comment: Does your Convert method get called?

Comment: @mm8 I tried debugging and I think it's not getting called

Comment: @mm8 DataTemplate is defined on a ResourceDictionary outside of the Window

Comment: if you binding errors it will generally write the error to the output window not break the code, check there for any error messages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by @Funk you return the wrong kind of brushes. You should return a `System.Windows.Media.Brush` object:

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    BooleanObject boolobject = (BooleanObject)value;
    if (boolobject.IsBoolValueOne)
        return System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Green;
    else if (boolobject.IsBoolValueTwo)
        return System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Red;
    else if (boolobject.IsBoolValueThree)
        return (SolidColorBrush)(new BrushConverter().ConvertFrom("#d3d300"));

    return System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Black;
}
```

Then it should work provided that your binding to the `boolobject` property actually works. Otherwise your converter won't get invoked at all.

If you want to bind to the object itself, you should specify a path of '.':

```
<TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center">
    <Image Source="imgsource.png" Height="25" Width="25" />
    <Run Text="{Binding BooleanObjectName}" Foreground="{Binding Path=., Converter={StaticResource convAvailability}}"/>
</TextBlock>
```

Comment: Never mind. Solved this issue because my code didn't properly set the ComboBoxitem.IsSelected value.

Comment: "combobox item green selected". No one else but you can be supposed to know what that means. Did you put a breakpoint in the Convert method? What does the IsBoolValueOne, IsBoolValueTwo and IsBoolValueThree properties return? Probably false.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help !